# Missing ETH locked in contract

Tags: solidity, ether, metamask, scam

Can anyone help me with this please?  I stumbled across a very professional and well documented video on YouTube with a tutorial on using ETH to deploy a bot using Solidity on Ethereum.

Now my ETH is missing I can see where its gone to a contract but I can’t seem to recover it back. This is the created contract address:

0x1e19013d7eE4E6182257331D0f7879fa3475c4D8

This is the link to the code https://pastebin.com/raw/s6rzUNmt

The ability to sell back isn’t working, can anyone help me recover this back to my metamask account please?

Answer (score 2):

0x1e19013d7eE4E6182257331D0f7879fa3475c4D8 **is a normal EOA address**, not a contract. It's probably the scammer's account so unfortunately there is no way to get your funds back.

Comment: I thought as much! such a great scam if thats the case.  I can still see my 0.9 ETH if it is a scam why is it still sat there? Can't I go in and recover it?

Comment: They're in no hurry they might want to wait for more to accumulate before laundering it through tornado cash or something and no there is no way of recovering it I'm afraid.

Comment: Lesson learnt then! gutted, but it seemed so convincing to someone with a lack of knowledge in the smart contract space.  The scammer ever replied back to me on Telegram.